# Help with group by clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i write the following code

```
Post.find(:all,:group=>'comments')
```

It only gives me the first record with the matching no of comments and skips the other records with the matching no of comments.
On the other hand, if i do something like this

```
Post.count(:all, :group=>'comments')
```

It gives me

```
#<OrderedHash {1=>9}>
```

which means that I have 9 posts which have no of comments = 1 and that is the expected result.
Can i do something which gives me a ordered hash but groups of objects with the same no of comments i.e. The posts having equal no of comments are all grouped together and finally i get a hash of group of objects(having similar property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Post.find(:all).group_by &:comments
```